# SQL sort by each hour with different dates

Tags: sql, localdb

I have a sql table like this

```
occ_val     time
0           2/1/2022 3:35:08 pm
1           2/1/2022 3:59:08 pm
2           2/1/2022 4:55:08 pm
3           2/1/2022 5:32:08 pm
2           3/1/2022 4:43:08 pm
3           4/1/2022 2:15:08 pm
```

How to I sort by each hour to get this:

```
time            occ_val
2:00:00 pm       3
3:00:00 pm       1
4:00:00 pm       4
5:00:00 pm       3
```

Your help is very much appreciated :D

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You can do a group by on the hour and a sum of the occ_val. How exactly depends on the database you're using

Comment: Im using Microsoft Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a MySQL solution:

select DATE_FORMAT(min(`time`), '%h:00'),sum(occ_val) from tbl group by hour(`time`)

See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/czudbp5zug6HxX4TFV26GT/0

Comment: I would like to have all values (regardless of dates) of from 2pm to 3pm to be accounted for, your solution gave me
2:00:00 pm ----3

Comment: Is this what you wanted? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/czudbp5zug6HxX4TFV26GT/1

Comment: right now I'm calculating the sum of all occ_val numbers. In MySQL, you can use group_concat() to show the individual values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from YourTableName
ORDER BY (timeCol - FLOOR(CAST(timeCol AS float)) ASC
```